# is there any way to share on facebook without showing the share dialog box in ios

Tags: ios, xcode6, facebook-share

here is my code but am getting invalid `publish_streem`. Is there any way to share on facebook without showing the share dialog box in ios?

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore
                                      accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

//ACAccount *facebookAccount;

// Specify App ID and permissions
NSDictionary *options = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey:@"565048226932112",ACFacebookPermissionsKey:@[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],ACFacebookAudienceKey:ACFacebookAudienceFriends};

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];

    }
    else{

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alert show];
       // NSLog(@"Error :%@",error);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Facebook Graph API

**https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post**

Reference : **https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share**

// NOTE: pre-filling fields associated with Facebook posts,
// unless the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow of your app,
// can be against the Platform policies: https://developers.facebook.com/policy

// Put together the dialog parameters

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",
                               @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                               @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.", @"description",
                               @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",
                               @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                               nil];

// Make the request
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                        if (!error) {
                          // Link posted successfully to Facebook
                          NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
                        } else {
                          // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                          // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                          NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                        }
                      }];
```

Comment: i am using same code for post but it is not woking.it give me error like operation could't completed.Is there any publish_action we need to post?

Answer (score 0):

Using API calls

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",
                           @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                           @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.", @"description",
                           @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",
                           @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                           nil];

// Make the request
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                         parameters:params
                         HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                  completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                      // Link posted successfully to Facebook
                      NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
                    } else {
                      // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                      // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                      NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                    }
                  }];
```

Reference :- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share